# What does it mean for a power series to be 'defined' in this context?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

The following screenshot is taken from some lecture notes on combinatorics and discusses the possible ways of expressing a power series

[image: notes]

where $(5.2)$ refers to the power series given by the expansion of
$$
(1+x+x^2+\dots)(1+x^2+x^4+\dots)
$$

As stated in the screenshot, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ will converge iff $|x| < 1$. Does this mean that the expansion $(5.2)$ is only defined for $|x| < 1$?

Slightly further on in the lecture notes, the following is said:
[image: notes2]

However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) says that

> In mathematics, the radius of convergence of a power series is the radius of the largest disk in which the series converges. It is either a non-negative real number or $\infty$.

So what does it mean in my lecture notes when it say "*If* [the power series] has a positive radius of convergence..."? Surely this is a given, based on the Wikipedia definition?

Comment: You might find, by Hadamard's formula, a ‘radius’ equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two formal series with coefficients in a conmutative ring $\mathbb{A}$ (such as $\mathbb{C}$),

$$
f = \sum_{n\geq0}a_nX^n  \ , \ g = \sum_{n\geq0}b_nX^n \in \mathbb{A}[[X]] 
$$

you can define their product as the Cauchy product,

$$
fg = \sum_{n\geq0}(\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k})X^n
$$

Now, if $\mathbb{A} = \mathbb{C}$ and we see each series as the complex function they define, $f$ and $g$ converging over some set does not imply that the product converges, and therefore (as a function) $fg$ will be defined only if the series of the Cauchy product of $f$ and $g$ is indeed convergent on some disk, and that is the clarification that is being made in the text.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ and $g$ are analytic in domains $\Omega_f$, $\Omega_g$ containing the origin then the function
$$h(z):=f(z)\>g(z)$$
is analytic at least in the intersection $\Omega_f\cap\Omega_g$. If furthermore
$$f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j\quad\bigl(|z|<\rho_f\bigr),\qquad 
g(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k z^k\quad\bigl(|z|<\rho_g\bigr)$$
then 
$$h(z)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty c_r z^r\qquad\bigl(|z|<\min\{\rho_f,\rho_g\}\bigr)\ ,$$
whereby $$c_r:=\sum_{k=0}^r a_{r-k}b_k\ .$$